# Toggleclass doesn't seem to toggle class, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make a button toggle a class, as well as show another div below it.

[Here is a jsFiddle example I have made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/GkNk7/).

The first function works perfectly, shows and hides the div, but also I want the button itself to add and remove a class, I thought this would work but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("this").toggleClass("chev-up");
```

should be

```
$(this).toggleClass("chev-up");
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Knew it was something small like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `$("this")` to `$(this)`. You don't need the quotation marks in there, as `this` is a keyword that refers to itself.